# Using the apply / (array subscripting) method in a builder pattern

Tags: arrays, scala, apply

Given a trivial function returning an array:

```
scala> def methodReturnsArray() = { Array(1.0, 2.0) }
methodReturnsArray: ()Array[Double]
```

We can go ahead and invoke the function:

```
scala> val myarr = methodReturnsArray
myarr: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0)

scala> myarr(0)
res21: Double = 1.0
```

However, it is not possible to use the apply ( / array index semantics) directly:

```
scala> methodReturnsArray(0)
<console>:53: error: too many arguments for method methodReturnsArray: ()Array[Double]
              methodReturnsArray(0)
                                ^
```

The request is to explain *why* that were not possible as given. Secondarily: is there  some  way to get an "inline" invocation. I.e. not requiring to separate out the  steps: s

- (a) invoke the method and
- (b) access the specific element of the array (via apply())

on separate statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  Seconds after posting this I arrived at the answer: need to include the parens on the function call:   i.e  *methodReturnsArray* **()** (0)  :

```
scala> methodReturnsArray()(0)
res22: Double = 1.0
```

Comment: You can also call `apply` explicitly: `methodReturnsArray.apply(0)`